# Unix commands to find total count from log using cut

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am writing the deleted records count to a file in unix. Below is the structure of the log file.

Using unix commands how do i?

- Find total Count of deleted records?
- Find total Count of deleted
  records by Day?

Log file structure below:

> 2015-03-16 15:43:59 DEBUG LoadClass:147 - Deleted 10 from Table.
>
> 2015-03-17 15:44:59 DEBUG LoadClass:147 - Deleted 1 from Table.
>
> 2015-03-19 15:45:59 DEBUG LoadClass:147 - Deleted 5 from Table.
>
> 2015-03-19 15:46:59 DEBUG LoadClass:147 - Deleted 8 from Table.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `cut`? Using cut, you can *probably* get the date and number out of the log file, but you need other programs to perform the addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` to do it:

```
awk '/Deleted/{a[$1]+=$(NF-2); tot+=$(NF-2);} \
     END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i]; print "total:", tot}' file
```

You may want to adjust the *pattern* (`Deleted`) and field number of the record count (`NF-2`) if your file format is different from your example.

Comment: LIke Glenn noted in the comment, you can certainly get the fields using `cut` and then you need other ways (e.g. bash's associative arrays) to calculate the total. I really don't see why you *have to* use `cut` for this task.

Answer (score 1):

perl works well here:

```
perl -anE '
    if (/Deleted (\d+)/) {$total += $1; $count{$F[0]} += $1;}
  } END {
    say "total: $total";
    say "$_: $count{$_}" for (sort keys %count);
' file
```

```
total: 24
2015-03-16: 10
2015-03-17: 1
2015-03-19: 13
```

Further explanation upon request.

Comment: That wasn't a requirement of your question. Do you need to edit your question?